# socket: Address family not supported by protocol in ninfod.service

Tags: sockets, service, protocols, buildroot

I'd generate an OS for an embedded system (based on a i.MX 6Quad Cortex-A9 processor) using buildroot 2020.02. Here are some of my toolchain option :

```
BR2_GCC_VERSION_8_X=y
BR2_GDB_VERSION_8_3=y
BR2_BINUTILS_VERSION_2_33_X=y.
```

When I do a : `systemctl --failed` , one service failed : it's node.service and it status is the following :

```
 ninfod.service - Respond to IPv6 Node Information Queries
 Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ninfod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-07-27 08:26:32 UTC; 6min ago
 Process: 2834 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ninfod -d (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2834 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

When i execute the executable here is the message error : [ERR] socket: Address family not supported by protocol. So I think it's an C error comming from the source file ninfod.c

I don't have any precision about this error ; does anyone know how to fix it ?

Comment: This sounds like ninfod is using a protocol that is not enabled in your kernel configuration. Check the source code of ninfod.c to see which `AF_` it uses, then check your kernel configuration to see if it is enabled.